# How to select all the last row of some column scope in MySQL

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I need a query to select the last rows of some column scope.

Example, the whole table:

```
----------------------
| ID | NAME | FOO_ID |
|--------------------|
| 1  | jQue |   2    |
| 2  | Prot |   2    |
| 3  | Node |   2    |
| 4  | Moo  |   1    |
| 5  | Scri |   1    |
----------------------
```

Rows returned by query, that returns all the "last row" in `FOO_ID` column scope:

```
----------------------
| ID | NAME | FOO_ID |
|--------------------|
| 3  | Node |   2    |
| 5  | Scri |   1    |
----------------------
```

Can someone help me in how to code this query?

Comment: But last FOO_ID is Node, not Prot

Comment: How do you define the 'last' row? Are you ordering by ID? Are you looking for the last item of its (FOO_ID) type inserted into the table

Comment: Im looking for the row with higher ID.

Comment: Follow the `greatest-n-per-group` tag for dozens of other similar questions on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use whichever of these you find most clear:

- a1ex07's query

or

```
SELECT *
  FROM the_table
 WHERE id IN
        ( SELECT MAX(id)
            FROM the_table
           GROUP
              BY foo_id
        )
;
```

or

```
SELECT *
  FROM the_table a
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
        ( SELECT 1
            FROM the_table b
           WHERE b.foo_id = a.foo_id
             AND b.id > a.id
        )
;
```

or

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM the_table a
  LEFT
 OUTER
  JOIN the_table b
    ON b.foo_id = a.foo_id
   AND b.id > a.id
 WHERE b.id IS NULL
;
```

(My own preference is the version with `IN`, but you may feel differently.)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM table_1 a
INNER JOIN (SELECT foo_id, max(id) as max_id FROM table_1 GROUP BY foo_id)b
ON b.max_id = a.id
```